# When matDialog pop'ups, it adds aria-hidden to <app-root> element

Tags: angular, accessibility, mat-dialog

When scanning page with ARC Toolkit (Accessibility testing plugin), if modal is opened, scanner shows error, because there is aria-hidden on parent () of one or more focusable child elements.

I have removed aria-hidden with jQuery, but is there any way, to prevent adding aria-hidden on app root by default in Angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hiding all other contents while a *modal* dialog is open from assistive technology (AT) is standard procedure.

Since AT provides a bunch of techniques to navigate a web page, not only focus needs to be restricted to the dialog, but any access to the underlying content.

Since ARIA 1.1, [the `aria-modal` attribute](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#aria-modal) should be set on the dialog, which should render all other contents inert. This does not work everywhere, yet.

So as the [APG mention on inert](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/dialogmodal/#h-note-7):

> However, in legacy dialog implementations where `aria-hidden` is used to make content outside a dialog inert for assistive technology users, it is important that:
>
> - `aria-hidden` is set to true on each element containing a portion of the inert layer.
> - The dialog element is not a descendant of any element that has `aria-hidden` set to true.

To avoid the latter case, usually, dialogs are put *outside* the app-root via portals or similar, so that the app-root can be hidden.

If I inspect the [Angular Material dialog example](https://v5.material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview), the `cdk-overlay-container`, which contains the dialog, is well placed along with `material-docs-app`, which is the app-root.

The warning can be [discarded, as this github issue also supports](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/25664)